# how to Randomly rotate images javascript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

how do i randomly rotate the images without refreshing the page with setTimeout??

js:

```
  var bannerImages = new Array( );

  bannerImages[0] = "Banner1.jpg";
  bannerImages[1] = "Banner2.jpg";
  bannerImages[2] = "Banner3.jpg";
  bannerImages[3] = "Banner4.jpg";

  var randomImageIndex = Math.round( Math.random( ) * 3 );
  document.write( "<img alt=\"\" src=\"imgs/" + bannerImages[randomImageIndex] + "\">" );
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the src attribute of the image:

```
<img id="pic" src="http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png" />

function changeImage()
{
    var bannerImages = new Array( );

    bannerImages[0] = "http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png";
    bannerImages[1] = "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png";
    bannerImages[2] = "http://jsfiddle.net/img/info-close.png";

    var image = document.getElementById('pic');
    var randomImageIndex = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * bannerImages.length );
    image.src = bannerImages[randomImageIndex];
}
window.setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/A3v8w/

Comment: In order to have something as close as possible to an uniform distribution, you have to use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)`. Also, he may want to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

Comment: what do you mean by "change the src attribute of the image" ?

Comment: Look at what the script does and try it. You create the image once and then you change the path to the image you want to show.

Comment: I thought I did... I made some changes and a link to a working example

Answer (score 0):

Using JqueryRotate  plugin, we can do it easily & more smoothly, **with only 1 image**

For e.g-

```
var angle = 0;
setInterval(function(){
      angle+=3;
     $("#img").rotate(angle);
},50);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/**

Ref: **[jquery-plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)** & **[codes here](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples#Example_3)** .

Comment: Look at his code, he want's to rotate in the another dimension ;)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks Bill. will tk care of it.