# How to include links and sizes in random rotator javascript

Tags: javascript

This script:

```
<img id="pic" src="http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png" />

function changeImage()
{
var bannerImages = new Array( );

bannerImages[0] = "http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png";
bannerImages[1] = "http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png";
bannerImages[2] = "http://jsfiddle.net/img/info-close.png";

var image = document.getElementById('pic');
var randomImageIndex = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * bannerImages.length );
image.src = bannerImages[randomImageIndex];
}
window.setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```

(found at this thread [how to Randomly rotate images javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886040/how-to-randomly-rotate-images-javascript)) randomizes images; but I would like to be able to include everything inside the a tag in the array like this:

```
 bannerImages[2]="<a href='link.htm'><img src='/Images/image2.jpg' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>";
```

so that everything changes.  Also, would it be able to start with a random image? Or is that placeholder there so briefly that it doesn't matter?  Finally, I would have commented on that original thread but my rep isn't high enough yet.

Comment: nobody knows what "random rotator" means. the title you gave could have been better.

Comment: Sorry..I was thinking about that.  It's a rotator that rotates the images randomly, not in sequence.  If there's a term for that pls let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code and what you want to do is that you only have access to the image so you can only change its source or attributes.

If you want to change all of the content for the gallery area, you will need to to encase it within a div or set a previous container to an id and control it using `innerHTML`.

HTML

```
<div id="pic">
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function changeImage()
{
var bannerImages = new Array( );

bannerImages[0]="<a href='link.htm'><img src='http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>";
bannerImages[1]="<a href='link.htm'><img src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>";
bannerImages[2]="<a href='link.htm'><img src='/Images/image2.jpg' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>";

var container= document.getElementById('pic');
var randomImageIndex = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * bannerImages.length );
container.innerHTML= bannerImages[randomImageIndex];
}
window.setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```

If you want it to set a random banner image at first, just add the function onload of the page which can be done easily in the body tag `<body onload="changeImage();">`

Comment: That was great, thanks.  One more question - how can I make the transition between the slides smoother?  Like fade..It may seem obvious, but I am terrible with coding.  Fine with html and css, but terrible with programming languages.

Comment: @qazser since you are changing all the content, this request is a bit harder. You'll need to create a javascript loop that changes the opacity of the image after the function is called. It would also have to fade out the beginning image first. I can point you in the right direction. Use `element.style.opacity = "0.9";
element.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=90)'; ` to change the opacity and just set element as the image by giving each image the same id (since they are never on the page at the same time). Then put this in a timeout loop that progressively changes the opacity over a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multidimensional array, and store both your link url and image. This example stores the entire image tag, but you could just store the image's url and build your tag on the fly.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzv95w5h/)

html:

```
<a id="aFlip" href='link.htm'><img src='http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png' height='300' width='300' border='0' /></a>
```

js:

```
function changeImage() {
  var bannerImages = new Array( );

  bannerImages[0] = ['link.htm', "<img src='http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png' height='300' width='300' border='0' />"];
  bannerImages[1] = ['two.htm', "<img src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png' height='300' width='300' border='0' />"];
  bannerImages[2] = ['three.htm', "<img src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/info-close.png' height='300' width='300' border='0' />"];


  var image = document.getElementById('aFlip');
  var randomImageIndex = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * bannerImages.length );
  image.innerHTML = bannerImages[randomImageIndex][1];
  image.href = bannerImages[randomImageIndex][0];
}

window.setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```